# Wrapping a non-static method into std::function with "this" parameter bound using as little code as possible

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename ...Arguments>    
class CSignal
{
public:
    void connect(std::function<void(Arguments...)> target)
    {
        m_connections.emplace_back(target);
    }

private:
    mutable std::vector<std::function<void(Arguments...)>> m_connections;
};
```

And `connect` works great for static methods or global functions. Now, what if I want to pass a member method? It seems that here is my only option:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    void print(float a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
} st;

signal.connect(std::bind(&MyStruct::print, &st, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2));
```

It would suit me if I didn't have to specify placeholders which is quite cumbersome. So I try another approach. I add a new `connect` overload for member methods:

```
template <class T, typename Method>
void connect(const T* target, Method method)
{
    m_connections.emplace_back([=](Arguments... args){target->*method(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);});
}
```

And then:

```
 signal.connect(&st, &MyStruct::print);
```

But now I get a compilation error:

> term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

at

```
m_connections.emplace_back([=](Arguments... args){target->*method(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);});
```

What's the problem here? And is there any way to do this,  without declaring second `connect` overload or using `std::bind` with placeholders?

P. S. In my second `connect` overload, the template one, is there a way to specify explicitly that `Method` is a member method of `T` in the declaration of `Method` itself?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this question, was stuck at precisely the same point. I didn't understand though your use of the lambda expression. Could you point me to some documentation to read into this? Thank you

Comment: @Alex: I'm using a lambda to store `this`, so that I no longer have to specify it when calling `operator()`, i. e. calling the underlying class object's method. It's the easiest way I know to hide `this` for delayed calls. Is that what you don't understand?

Comment: My uncertainty was regarding your use of the lambda. I was trying an std::bind but could not get it to compile. Is the lambda being used to wrap the call to 'target->*method' ? thank you

Comment: @Alex: yes, that's right. All the code in my question will compile in any C++ 11 compiler (as long as you include the neccessary headers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When calling a member function through `->*` operator, you have to use parenthesis:

   ```
   (target->*method)(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
   ^               ^
   ```
2. When calling a member function through a pointer to `const` (you do, note `const T*`), that member function has to be `const` qualified:

   ```
   void print(float a, int b) const
                              ^^^^^
   ```
3. *Is there a way to specify explicitly that Method is a member method of T in the declaration of Method itself?*

   ```
   template <class T>
   void connect(const T* target, void (T::*method)(Arguments...) const)
   ```

Comment: Personally I'd go with `template <class T, class Return> void connect(const T* target, Return (T::*method)(Arguments...) const)` as this would allow usage with member functions that don't return `void` -- we'll just silently discard their return value.